# Insert if doesn't exist fail if table empty

Tags: mysql

I used the following command to avoid duplicates in a table :

```
INSERT INTO mytable (num,name)
SELECT 2,'example' FROM mytable WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE num=2 AND name='example') LIMIT 1;
```

It is working but NOT if `mytable` is empty.

mytable also contain a `AUTO_INCREMENT` id.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
 id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 num int(11) NOT NULL,
 name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Do you recommanded another method or a workaround ?

Comment: Is this a one-off, or does your table have a _requirement_ that the combination of `num,name` always be unique?  If so, you need to create a `UNIQUE` index on that pair of columns.

Comment: Try `SELECT 2,'example' FROM dual WHERE ...` instead.

Comment: what you mean isnt working?

Answer (score 0):

In my case replacing `mytable` by `DUAL` did the trick. (But i have no idea why)

```
INSERT INTO mytable (num,name)
SELECT 2,'example' FROM mytable WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE num=2 AND name='example') LIMIT 1;
```

Replaced by :

```
INSERT INTO mytable (num,name)
SELECT 2,'example' FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE num=2 AND name='example') LIMIT 1;
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Reason: `SELECT <no_matter_what> FROM mytable WHERE <something>` will return *no* records when `mytable` is empty. Using `dual`, you can also omit that `LIMIT 1` because `dual` has only one record.

Answer (score 0):

You can create **Unique** column by using MySQL **UNIQUE**

Just update your **CREATE TABLE** query like below

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  num int(11) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE (num) # You can define Unique column like this
);
```

**Note:** Then you no need to check **Unique** value when Save to Database.

And try to use normal SQL query for inserting Data

```
INSERT INTO mytable (num,name) VALUES(2,'example')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like 
Select * from tbl where _____ = ______

Then add if statement if results are available then insert or otherwise leave

Answer (score -1):

Why do not you simply use **INSERT IGNORE**. Also why do you want to copy the data from same table?